# Entering 'domain' information when connecting to SAMBA share in Dolphin

Tags: samba, kde-4, smb, dolphin-file-manager

openSUSE 11.2. KDE 4.3.5 Dolphin 1.3

The following works on CL

```
mount -v -o username=abcdefg,domain=DOM -t cifs //server.tld/share/path  /mnt
```

Authentication fails when trying to connect to this share via Dolphin. "domain=DOM" is a required field. How do I force dolphin to connect to it?

On Dolphin, the following fails:

```
smb://abcdefg@server.tld/server/path
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
smb://DOM%5Cabcdefg@server.tld/server/path
```

(%5C is the URL encoding of the backslash character)

Comment: It also worked by just typing in "dom\abcdefg" as my username when the dialog prompt opened.